# Gradient application temperature problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, problem-solving

I'm looking if someone could take me out of a doubt I have with this problem.

> Suppose temperature at a point $(x,y,z)$ in space is given by $T(x,y,z)=\frac{80}{1+x^2+2y^2+3z^2}$, where $T$ is measured in celsius and $x,y,z$ in meters. In what direction does the temperature increase more rapidly in relation to the point $P=(1,1,-2)?$

From what I know, a function $f$ changes more rapidly in a point $P$ in direction of it's gradient $\nabla f_{(P)}$ at that point, however, in the problem I'm asked in what direction the tempareture increase more rapidly, so this means that the direction of greater increase of temperature would be the negative of gradient of $T$ evaluated in $P$, am I right?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds about right, unless I missed something in your question. And it is pretty obvious in which direction (x,y or z) it moves more quickly in that point.

Comment: The resulting gradient vector will point towards the overall direction of increase. Therefore the direction required in the exercise is the gradient vector and not the opposite. The opposite of the gradient vector is the direction of maximum decrease of the function.

Comment: However, changes in temperature $T$ occur from high to low temperatures, so the gradient vector will point in the direction of greater change from high to low temperatures, but the problem is asking me the direction in which the temperature icnrease more rapidly, so it would be the contrary direction to the gradient in this case, wouldn't it?